# Failed to initialize Carto Mobile Maps SDK, native .so library failed to load?

Tags: java, android, amd-processor, cartodb

I am having this issue while running app on emulator in AMD Ryzen 500 Series processor. It is working fine in Intel based processor.

```
Failed to initialize Carto Mobile Maps SDK, native .so library failed to load? 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libcarto_mobile_sdk.so" not found at 
java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1082) at 
java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1003) at 
java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1661) at 
com.carto.ui.MapView.<clinit>(MapView.java:46) at 
com.mapsted.map.views.BaseMapFragment.initializeMapView(BaseMapFragment.java:424) at 
com.mapsted.map.views.BaseMapFragment.onCreateView(BaseMapFragment.java:243) at
androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2995) at 
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:523) at 
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261) at 
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1840) at 
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1758) at 
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1701) at 
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:488) at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958) at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at 
android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205) at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177) at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at 
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552) at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
```